# Qual é a vantagem de esconder o construtor da classe a favor de um método estático (no .NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Meu líder usa este padrão em TODAS as suas classes (darei os exemplos em C#, mas vale para qualquer linguagem do .NET):

```cs
public class MeuTipo
{
    private MeuTipo() { } // esconder o construtor

    public static MeuTipo CriarMeuTipo()
    {
        MeuTipo meuTipo = new MeuTipo();
        return meuTipo;
    }
}
```

Eu realmente não entendo o porquê disso. Suas classes sequer são imutáveis (apesar de que eu também não acho que existiria uma vantagem mesmo que a classe fosse imutável), então, além de isso me parecer um padrão sem muita utilidade, também nos previne de usar construtores com propriedades, como por exemplo... (Usarei uma suposta classe `Pessoa`)

```cs
new Pessoa { Nome = "João", Sobrenome = "Doe", (...) } // não é possível nesse padrão
```

Por isso, somos obrigados a imaginar todos os cenários em que um construtor seria possível. Por exemplo, supondo que em uma ocasião a `Pessoa` pode iniciar sem nenhum dado, ou só com o primeiro nome, ou com ambos os nomes, somos obrigados a fazer a classe assim:

```cs
public class Pessoa {
    private string _nome;
    public string nome {
        get { return this._nome; }
        set { this._nome = value; }
    }

    private string _sobrenome;
    public string sobrenome {
        get { return this._sobrenome; }
        set { this._sobrenome = value; }
    }

    private Pessoa() { }
    public static Pessoa CriarPessoa() {
        return CriarPessoa(null);
    }
    public static Pessoa CriarPessoa(string nome) {
        return CriarPessoa(null, null);
    }
    public static Pessoa CriarPessoa(string nome, string sobrenome) {
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.nome = nome;
        pessoa.sobrenome = nome;
        return pessoa;
    }
}
```

Enquanto poderíamos fazer assim:

```cs
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
}
```

Eu realmente não consigo entender o porquê de fazer tanto trabalho para perder um recurso da linguagem, então não consigo deixar de pensar que possa existir um motivo pra isso. Se há um motivo, sejam Design Patterns ou algum tipo de motivo por legacy code, alguém pode me esclarecer?

**Nota**: Eu **NÃO** quero opiniões aqui, porque este não é um site de opiniões. Eu fiz essa pergunta porque creio que algum programador de mais tempo que eu, ou que tenha trabalhado com Orientação a Objetos fora do .NET me dê uma resposta para o porquê isso seria uma vantagem.

Aliás, meu líder usou Java no passado. Por isso eu acho que exista uma resposta *certa* pra essa pergunta.

Comment: Eu ia comentar exatamente sua ultima linha. Eu vi esse pattern em programadores Java, porém não vejo vantagem no .net

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esse padrão é útil em raros casos.

Um deles é para implementar o padrão Singleton, em que se esconde o constructor, e um método estático é utilizado para criar um Singleton novo ou retornar o existente. De modo simples:

```cs
public class MySingleton{    
    private static MySingleton _singleton = null;

    private MySingleton() { }

    public static MySingleton GetInstance() {
        if(_singleton == null)
            _singleton = new MySingleton();
        return _singleton;
    }
}
```

(Nota: o exemplo acima podia ser melhorado, com *double-checked locking* por exemplo para garantir *thread safety*)

Porem, na maior parte dos casos, tornar *todos* os constructores privados só traz problemas.
Impede testes unitários em isolação, não se pode fazer mocking de dependências, não se pode injectar dependências, etc.

Com todo o respeito, o teu líder devia voltar para a faculdade...

Comment: +1 pela resposta **certa** como eu pedi. E eu queria dar +10 pelo comentário no final. xD (Nota: Ele **não** usa o padrão singleton -- tampouco faz testes unitários ou mocking)

Comment: @AndréLeria pergunta ao teu lider quais as vantagens de usar essa abordagem em todas as classes.. ficaria surpreendido se ele conseguisse dar *uma* vantagem pertinente...

Comment: Eu o questiono sempre que sinto que posso perguntar sem correr risco de ser queimado diante de meu chefe. Mas não posso mais contar com suas respostas, pois assim como nessa pergunta, já comprovei que muito do que ele diz que são boas práticas é inútil (assim como ele já me disse que boas práticas são más práticas...)

Comment: @AndréLeria Sempre que suspeitares das dicas do teu lider, pergunta aqui no SO ;) Nao ha lideres! Se a resposta estiver correcta e fundamentada, upvote - caso contrario, downvote! Democracia para todos :D

Comment: Só pra complementar, esse padrão é útil também quando há necessidade de se controlar o uso de recursos (isto é, controlar a instanciação de objetos da classe). Exemplo clássico em jogos: um míssel lançado por uma nave, que ao "sair" da tela pode ser reutilizado sem a necessidade de instanciar um novo objeto. Adicionalmente aos problemas citados pelo @dcastro, esse padrão também podem dificultar ou impedir o uso de reflexão (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) em algumas linguagens, uma vez que o construtor da classe é privado.

Comment: Note também que, uma vez que só há um construtor e ele é privado, o construtor não pode ser usado em subclasses (vide essa thread do SO para mais detalhes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661595/why-can-you-not-inherit-from-a-class-whose-constructor-is-private). Assim, caso o padrão seja necessário, talvez seja melhor declarar o construtor como protegido ao invés de privado.

Answer (score 10):

Existem dois padrões (que eu me lembre agora) que se beneficiam de construtores
que não são públicos:

- Factory
- Singleton

Nenhum desses dois padrões se beneficia de um método estático de construção...
o singleton possui sim um método (ou propriedade) estático, mas não é de construção e sim de
obtenção da instância, que pode ou não construir o objeto.

Existe entretanto, um propósito para métodos de construção estáticos:

- construção com inferência de tipos dos argumentos
- construção com semântica (muito importante para manutenibilidade)

### Padrão Factory

O padrão **Factory** determina que um objeto seja construído por uma fábrica de
objetos. Essa fábrica de objetos implementa uma interface, de forma que se pode
usar inversão de controle (IoC) da construção de objetos, ou seja, externalizar
a construção de objetos, sendo que a fábrica de objetos se torna uma dependência
de todos que necessitarem construir o objeto.

```
public interface IFabricaMeuObjeto
{
    MeuObjeto Criar(int exemploParametro);
}
```

Nesse padrão o construtor dos objetos não é público, para que os programadores
não sejam induzidos a criar o objeto usando um construtor, ao invés de usar a fábrica
de objetos. Neste caso não seria `private` mas sim `internal`.

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    internal MeuObjeto()
    {
    }

    public int Inteiro { get; set; }
}
```

**Utilidades do padrão factory**

Esse é um padrão muito útil, pois permite em mockar a construção de novos
objetos, além de permitir fazer programação orientada a aspectos, por exemplo,
se você quiser fazer um LOG de todas as vezes em que um objeto é criado, você
pode implementar a interface da fábrica de objetos, recebendo a fábrica original
e implementar o LOG assim:

```
public class FabricaMeuObjeto : IFabricaMeuObjeto
{
    public MeuObjeto Criar(int exemploParametro)
    {
        return new MeuObjeto { Inteiro = exemploParametro };
    }
}

public class FabricaMeuObjetoLog : IFabricaMeuObjeto
{
    IFabricaMeuObjeto original;

    public FabricaMeuObjetoLog(IFabricaMeuObjeto original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public MeuObjeto Criar(int exemploParametro)
    {
        return this.original.Criar(exemploParametro);
        Log.CriarLog("MeuObjeto foi criado.");
    }
}
```

Na inicialização do sistema, usando algum framework de injeção de dependências:

```
container.Register<IFabricaMeuObjeto, FabricaMeuObjetoLog>();
```

Usei o [SimpleInjector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/) nesse exemplo.

### Padrão Singleton

O padrão singleton é muito útil para objetos de que só se necessita de uma
instância em todo o tempo de execução do programa. Sendo assim, o construtor do
objeto não deve ser público, de forma a não induzir os programadores que
utilizam o objeto ao erro.

O singleton é obtido de uma chamada estática, entretanto não vejo problemas em
fazer esse singleton ser obtido a partir de um framework de injeção de
dependências. O SimpleInjector (que é o que eu uso) suporta uma forma de injeção
em que sempre é injetado o mesmo objeto, quando ele é necessário... para mim é
uma boa forma de integrar dois padrões muito úteis, fornecendo a instância única
através de uma interface de serviço:

```
public interface ISingletonService
{
    MeuObjeto PegarInstancia();
}

public interface SingletonService
{
    public MeuObjeto PegarInstancia()
    {
        return MeuObjeto.Instancia;
    }
}

public class MeuObjeto
{
    internal static MeuObjeto Instancia { get; private set; }

    static MeuObjeto()
    {
        Instancia = new MeuObjeto();
    }

    private MeuObjeto()
    {
    }
}
```

Na inicialização do sistema, usando algum framework de injeção de dependências,
que neste caso é o SimpleInjector:

```
container.Register<ISingletonService, SingletonService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

### Construção com inferência de tipos genéricos

Uma utilidade que vejo para métodos de construção estáticos, é fazer inferência
de tipos de um contrutor de um objeto que possui parâmetros genéricos, uma vez
que o C# não aceita fazer inferência de tipos quando usando o operador `new`.
Isso não funciona no C#:

```
public class MeuObjeto<T>
{
    public T Valor { get; set; }

    public MeuObjeto(T valor)
    {
        this.Valor = valor;
    }
}

...

var obj = new MeuObjeto( 1 ); // o C# não vai inferir o construtor a ser usado
```

Vai ocorrer o seguinte erro de compilação:

> Using the generic type 'MeuObjeto' requires 1 type arguments

Para isso pode ser criado um método estático, em uma outra classe, de forma que
se possa tomar vantagem da inferência de tipos para criar o objeto:

```
public static class MeuObjeto
{
    public static MeuObjeto<T> Criar<T>(T valor)
    {
        return new MeuObjeto<T>(valor);
    }
}

...

var objInt = MeuObjeto.Criar( 1 ); // isso funciona
var objStr = MeuObjeto.Criar( "string" ); // isso também funciona
```

### Construção de objeto com semântica

Quando um construtor possui um significado específico, que seria melhor expresso
através de um método com um nome específico, eu prefiro usar métodos de construção
do que o operador `new`. Um bom exemplo no framework .Net é o `TimeSpan`, que
possui vários métodos de construção estáticos, que não poderiam ser expressos
usando-se construtores:

- `TimeSpan.FromDays`
- `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`
- `TimeSpan.FromTicks`

Quando houver semântica na construção, provavelmente o nome do método não vai ser
somente `Criar`... pois "criar" não apresenta nenhuma semântica melhor do que o
próprio `new`.

Comment: Ótima explicação. Pena que meu líder não usa nenhum desses...

Answer (score 1):

Essa forma de trabalhar com o construtor é muito utilizado no padrão de projetos Singleton. Respondendo de fato a pergunta, não é boa prática tratar todas as classes dessa forma. Tente conversar com o seu líder e entender o porquê de fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Objetos Imutáveis.

O padrão para definição de objetos imutáveis normalmente é a definição de um construtor privado/protegido, a ausência de set's e a definição de construtores para o correto preenchimento da instância.

O código fica mais "estranho", mas para quem quer trabalhar com programação paralela (e objetos imutáveis são essenciais nesse modelo de programação), não existe outra forma.

Isso vale também para as linguagens híbridas, por exemplo, Scala (funcional e orientada à objetos).

Se a intenção não é trabalhar com objetos imutáveis e não existe a necessidade de uma solução de paralelismo, não vejo sentido em usar esse padrão. Objetos imutáveis tendem a diminuir os bugs de efeitos colaterais, mas exige um bom planejamento arquitetural.

Veja uma definição em
[Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html)

Comment: Como assim "não existe outra forma"? É perfeitamente possível usar um construtor com objetos imutáveis.

Comment: Não é aconselhável, porque você obrigatoriamente terá de fornecer métodos set, o que quebra o "padrão" de definição de objetos imutáveis. Esse "padrão" força com que o desenvolvedor seja obrigado a SEMPRE criar uma nova instância, ao invés de atualizar a mesma.

Comment: Tanto no .NET como em outras plataformas, isso se resolve facilmente definindo setters privados (no caso de auto-propriedades) ou simplesmente não definindo setters (no caso de encapsulamento). Ainda não vejo porque não é aconselhável, ou porque não existiria outra forma.

Comment: @HaßlocherMarcelo Isso nao faz sentido nenhum. Se eu quiser criar uma classe imutavel, eu crio os constructores necessarios, com os argumentos necessarios. Privatizar os constructores e criar metodos *factory* estaticos nao ajuda na imutabilidade da classe.

Comment: Pensa que você quer forçar o desenvolvedor a sempre criar uma nova instância. Como você faria isso? Você não pode permitir ele usar set´s. E cada vez que mudar algum valor no objeto, seja forçado a criar uma nova instância. O único jeito é tornar o construtor privado/protegido, retirar todos os set´s e fornecer novos construtores onde o desenvolvedor é obrigado a fornecer os valores. Os métodos factory não fazem parte desse padrão. Lembrem-se, estou falando apenas do construtor padrão, sem parâmetros.

Comment: @MarceloHaßlocher Para isso existem os construtores com mais parâmetros. Eu não vejo como um método estático pode ser mais eficiente que um construtor para classes imutáveis. [Exemplo](http://ideone.com/AEdeA0)

Comment: @MarceloHaßlocher 1) A pergunta nao se trata de esconder "apenas do construtor padrão, sem parâmetros". Trata-se de "esconder o construtor da classe a favor de um método estático". 2) O constructor padrao, sem parametros, pode ser util para objectos imutaveis - pode inicializer o objecto com valores padrao. Imutabilidade nao tem nada a ver com esconder construtores - e muito menos com metodos estaticos. Scala, por exemplo, promove a utilizacao de objectos imutaveis e - *shocker!* - tecnicamente nao existem sequer metodos estaticos.

Comment: Para tornar uma classe imutavel, basta apagar todos os setters (publicos ou nao) e tornar os fields privados `readonly`.

Comment: Os métodos estáticos não fazem parte do "padrão" que citei. Eles realmente não podem ser usados como substitutos de construtores. O fato é que em C#, pelo pouco que sei, não tem como esconder o construtor default (salvo algumas gambiarras). Em Java, pode-se fazer isso e o compilador reclama se você tentar instanciar com o construtor default, o que torna a criação de objetos imutáveis mais fácil. Em Scala, o fato de termos como declarar qualquer coisa como **val** ajuda muito no uso de imutabilidade. O ponto é que acredito que o líder tentou trazer uma ideia, mas definiu da forma errada.

Comment: @MarceloHaßlocher Em C# você esconde o construtor default do mesmo jeito que no Java.